# Solr reports "Slave in sync with master." upon replication but index version differs from master index version

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, replication, master-slave

Any time I try to replicate, the solr slave (version 3.5.0) reports in the logs that "Slave in sync with master.". However, for one of the cores, the slave has version 1329924432722, generation 9244, which is 7.7GB, and the master has 1329924433193, generation 9266, which is about 8.5GB.

What could be causing this to happen?

**EDIT:** It seems I've found the problem - once I issued an 'optimize' command to the Solr master instance, replication occured. Is there a solrconfig variable that controls whether replication can only happen when the index has been optimized?

Comment: Do you have replicateAfter set for optimize? Please refer http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/Index+Replication

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the core that is reporting that - "salve in sync with master" is different from the one that is problematic?

I'd comment all the other cores in solr.xml (if possible) and only run the problematic core to begin with.

After the slave downloads the new index segments, it issues a commit.  The commit may result in running a search warming query.  Do you have a large search warming query?

Comment: Nope, afraid not - there are only two cores and it's definitely the same core causing problems across slave and master. Commenting out the other core isn't an option, unfortunately, as this is a problem we're only experiencing in our production environment. As for cache warming, we do no warming queries...